# How do make a random.math int populate with every iteration of a function?

Tags: lua, macros, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I'm creating my first ever coding project, a macro for my Logitech mouse using Lua, and I have a repeating function (autoclick) that I would like to generate a random delay between clicks.

I want it to be:

- toggle-able with "scroll lock"
- adjustable delay on the fly
- to simply click and hold left-click to use

My code is as follows:

```
    --Button used to turn rapid fire on/off
rfLock="scrolllock"


--Rapid fire values used in randomization/realism, in ms (milleseconds).
rfLo=45
rfHi=75

EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);

function RapidFire()
    if (rfLock==true) then
    if (IsMouseButtonPressed(1)==true)then
    repeat
    ReleaseMouseButton(1)
    sleep (math.random(rfLo,rfHi))
    PressMouseButton(1)
    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)

function OnEvent(event, arg)    

if IsKeyLockOn(rfLock)then
        rFire=true
    else
        rFire=false
    end
    
end
```

Is there another way I have to approach this? It currently does not do anything. I'm still trying to figure it out obviously, just thought I could get the knowledge from you guys here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `adjustable delay on the fly` mean?  Is it a synonym for "random delay"?  Or do you want to somehow control the delay manually in the game?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using GHUB (but the same could be done in LGS).

**Step 0.**
You are about to modify the behavior of Left Mouse Button.
This is a potentially dangerous operation: you can do nothing on your computer without LMB.
So you must create a "spare LMB".
For example, if you don't use Mouse Button 8, you can make it acting like a clone on LMB.
Go to GHUB (mouse device, "Assignments" screen, SYSTEM tab).
Bind "Primary click" to your physical MB#8.
Now, if something goes wrong and your LMB stops working, you can press MB#8 instead of LMB.

It might happen that you don't want to expend a mouse button for "spare LMB" because all the mouse buttons are in use for something important.
If you have a Logitech keyboard you can use one of its G-buttons as "spare LMB" (keyboard device, "Assignments" screen, SYSTEM tab).

---

**Step 1.**
Do you use Mouse Button 4 ("back") in the game?

- If YES (some action is assigned to MB#4 in the game), proceed to "Step 2".
- If NO (the game ignores MB#4 press), skip "Step 2" and proceed to "Step 3".

---

**Step 2.**
You have to remap game action from MB#4 to some other key.
Do the following:

- choose keyboard button you don't currently use in the game
  (let's assume the `F12` key is not currently used)
- go to GHUB (mouse device, "Assignments" screen, KEYS tab);
  bind `F12` to your physical MB#4
- go to game options;
  assign the game action to `F12` instead of MB#4

Now when you press physical MB#4, the game receives `F12` and activates the game action.
Skip "Step 3" and proceed to "Step 4".

---

**Step 3.**
Go to GHUB (mouse device, "Assignments" screen).
Unbind "Back" from physical MB#4 (click and select DISABLE from the drop-down menu).
Disabled MB#4 will look like a white circle with black inside.

---

**Step 4.**
Set the script (see below).

---

**Step 5.**
Go to GHUB (mouse device, "Assignments" screen, SYSTEM tab).
Bind "Back" to your physical LMB.
You will see a warning about a potentially dangerous operation.
Allow this operation because you have the "spare LMB".

```
--Button used to turn rapid fire on/off
local rfLock = "scrolllock"

--Rapid fire values used in randomization/realism, in ms (milleseconds).
local rfLo = 45
local rfHi = 75

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
      PressMouseButton(1)
      if IsKeyLockOn(rfLock) then
         repeat
            Sleep(math.random(rfLo,rfHi))
            if not IsMouseButtonPressed(4) then break end
            ReleaseMouseButton(1)
            Sleep(math.random(rfLo,rfHi))
            PressMouseButton(1)
         until not IsMouseButtonPressed(4)  -- 4 = "Back"
      end
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 1 then
      ReleaseMouseButton(1)
   end
end
```